# Rxjs - reassigning an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing

I'm using Angular 7, and I'm trying to get data from my routes.

I have my lazy loaded routes set up like so:

```
  {
    data: { menuItems: DASHBOARD_MENU_ITEMS },
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
  },
  {
    data: { menuItems: ADMIN_MENU_ITEMS },
    path: 'admin', 
    loadChildren: './modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' 
  }
```

And I have an observable to get that data like so:

```
menuItems$: Observable<any[]>;
```

In one of my components, I have the following:

```
this.menuItems$ = this.route.firstChild.firstChild.data;

    this.menuItems$ = this.router.events.pipe(
      // startWith(this.route.firstChild.firstChild.data),
      filter(e => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
      map((event: RoutesRecognized) => {
        console.log(event.state.root.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.data)
        return event.state.root.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.data as NbMenuItem[];
      }));
```

But this isn't working for me, as I believe I am reassigning my observable variable `menuItems$`.

I need to do this as I need to get the data both the first time a route is hit (which does not trigger an event from `this.router.events`), and every time the user navigates.

If I use the `.subscribe()` notation, then it works fine, but I don't want to do that. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're passing an Observable into `startWith` rather than passing the initial state. You can grab the initial state using the `snapshot` property.

You'll also need to place the `startWith` operator after the `filter` and `map`.

```
const initialMenuItems = this.route.firstChild.firstChild.snapshot.data;

this.menuItems$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
  map((event: RoutesRecognized) => {
    console.log(event.state.root.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.data);
    return event.state.root.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.data as NbMenuItem[];
  }),
  startWith(this.route.firstChild.firstChild.data)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `shareReplay()` so that the observable replays the last emitted value.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

```
this.menuItems$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
  map((event: RoutesRecognized) => event.state.root.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.data),
  startWith(this.route.firstChild.firstChild.data),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

You should also move the `startWith()` after the `filter()` so that the first value is not removed by the filter.

I'm not completely sure the above is correct. I'm just taking a guess.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid :(